# Sensu transport handler define max record count

Tags: sensu

I have some sensu metric check with transport handler defined on it. My transport is Redis and I can see that every metric cycle new record added to redis, however I would like to define max records limit or record TTL so I won't store endless metrics data in redis. How can I do it from handler json declaration? Here is my handler definition:

```
{
  "handlers": {
    "redis_handler": {
      "type": "transport",
      "mutator": "only_check_output",
      "pipe": {
        "type": "direct",
        "name": "example_handler_queue"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [occurences filter extension](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-extensions-occurrences) for sensu,

> The occurrences filter will determine if an event occurrence count
>   meets the user defined requirements in the event check definition.
>   Users can specify a minimum number of occurrences before an event will
>   be passed to a handler. Users can also specify a refresh time, in
>   seconds, to reset where recurrences are counted from.